# Conjugation оf "врач"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am new to this language. I would need some help with the conjugation. Please check if I got it right.

In this specific case G=A.

N хороший врач

A хорошeго врач-a

G хорошeго врач-a

D хорошemy врач-y

I хорошиm врач-om

P хорошom врач-e

Comment: `In this specific case G=A` It stands like this as it's an _animate_ noun of 2nd declension (i.e. all masculine except few ending in -а/-я).

Comment: Diana, if you go to rifmovnik.ru and enter any word or word form in the search field, and then select словоформы from the dropdown menu, it will give you full declensions of nouns and adjectives, and full conjugations of verbs - all with stress indicated throughout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

N Хороший врач

A Хорошeго врач-а

G хорошeго врач-а

D хорошeмy врач-у

I хорошим врач-ом

Р хорошем врач-е

Comment: Не во всём согласен с Вами: D хорошeмy врач-У; Р хорошЕМ врач-е.

Comment: И ещё, Диана: Вы пишите латинскую букву "m" вместо буквы "м".

Comment: Я знаю. Это было не специально. Я был в спешке. Не означало проявить неуважение. Пожалуйста, примите моя извинения.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин пиш**е**те :)

Comment: Да, конечно, - пишете.:)

Comment: Всё в порядке, Диана. Вам не за что извиняться.

Comment: @Диана if you are female, then you былА в спешке.

Comment: @Диана thank you for your effort to learn Russian and no worries, here everybody respects your attitude.